# Bind returned data from ajax to aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, webforms

I have ajax that sends paramether(Value) to procedure in C# on button click.

```
$(document).on('click', ".Btn", function () {
    header = $(this).closest('tr').find('.ColumnID').text()
    console.log(Value);   

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "MyAdmin.aspx/GetObject",
        data: JSON.stringify({ 'Value': Value }),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
 success: function (data) {
           if(data.d.length>0)
           {
             $.each(data,function(i,values){
             values.id;
             values.name;
             values.value;
             });
           }

        }

        error: function () {
        }
    });
});
```

The parameter(Value) is received by WebMethod and used in a procedure((getObj.getValuesTableAdapter(Value);). Datatable through list is then successfully returned to ajax(   values.id; , values.name;  values.value;)

C# part:

```
public class DataForClientSide
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string value{ get; set; }
    }
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]

    public static DataForClientSide[] GetObject(int Value)
    {
List<DataForClientSide> details = new List<DataForClientSide>();
        LogicTableAdapters.getValuesTableAdapter getObj = new LogicTableAdapters.getValuesTableAdapter();

        DataTable getObj = getObj.getValuesTableAdapter(Value);
        DataTable dtObj = new DataTable();
        dtObj.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[4]{ new DataColumn("ObjectID", typeof(string)), new DataColumn("ObjectName", typeof(string)), new DataColumn("ObjectValue", typeof(string)),

                    });

        foreach (DataRow dr in getObj.Rows)
        {
                        DataForClientSide Info= new DataForClientSide();
                        Info.id = dr["ObjectID"].ToString();
                        Info.name = dr["ObjectName"].ToString();
                        Info.value = dr["ObjectValue"].ToString();
                        //multiple data as u want. . . . . 
                        details.Add(Info);

        }
        return details.ToArray();
    }
```

Now I need to bind those values(id, name, value) that are returned to ajax to aspx.
This is my aspx code.

```
 <asp:GridView ID="gvMyObjects" runat="server" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" CssClass="GridView" AutoPostBack="False"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" >

            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
            <Columns>

                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
  <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
                        <button class="myBtn" id="Button1" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" style="vertical-align: middle" onserverclick="Button1_click"   OnClientClick="return false;" runat="server" ><span>Select</span></button>
 </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID" >
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="ID" runat="server" class="ObjekatID" Width="118px" Height="36px"  style="text-align:center" Font-Names="Georgia"  margin-Left="100px"  Text='<%# Bind("ID") %>'></asp:Label>


                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
                    <ItemTemplate>

                        <asp:Label ID="Name" runat="server" Width="118px" Height="26px" style="text-align:center" Font-Names="Georgia" margin-Left="100px" Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>'></asp:Label>

                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Value">
                    <ItemTemplate>

                        <asp:Label ID="Value" runat="server" Width="118px" Height="26px" style="text-align:center" Font-Names="Georgia" margin-Left="100px" Text='<%# Bind("Value") %>'></asp:Label>

                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

            </Columns>


        </asp:GridView>
```

Can someone help me with this bind part of the code. 
I think I need to do something in the ajax.

Returend json.  0 in one row, 1 in second row and 2... in third row in table that has to be shown.

```
d   […]
0   {…}
ID  Name
Name    ObjectNameZero
Value   Somevalue

1   {…}
ID  1
Name    ObjectNameOne
Value   MyValus1
2   {…}
ID  2
Name    ObjectNameTwo
Value   MyValus2
3   {…}    
ID  3
Name    ObjectNameThree
Value   MyValus3
```

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use simple `tr` `td` append inside your ajax success function like this

```
$(document).on('click', ".Btn", function () {
    header = $(this).closest('tr').find('.ColumnID').text()
    console.log(Value);   

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "MyAdmin.aspx/GetObject",
        data: JSON.stringify({ 'Value': Value }),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
 success: function (data) {
           if(data.d.length>0)
           {
             var newRows="";
             $.each(data,function(i,values){
             values.id;
             values.name;
             values.value;
             newRows +="<tr><td>"+values.id+"</td><td>"+values.name+"</td><td>"+values.value+"</td></tr>";
             });
             $("#gvMyObjects").append(newRows);
           }

        }

        error: function () {
        }
    });
});
```

You need to decide how you want to show returned values as it is inside each function which will show only last iterated values only.

Comment: The problem is that I have several iterations :/

Comment: how you want to show your data? you want to concatenate all results with some char like `,` or something

Comment: Thanks for your resposne :) I updated my question, hope thats gives an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can post the data to a handler that will do the required logic and then render and return the grid view that you are already using. Then, you will have to replace the old grid with the new rendered one

Answer (score 1):

The `GridView` itself is a table element. If you want to append data with existing data in table, use `<tr>` and `<td>` tags to build additional rows:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "MyAdmin.aspx/GetObject",
    data: JSON.stringify({ 'Value': Value }),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        if (data.d.length > 0) {
            $.each(data, function (i, values) {
                // build table data
                $('#gvMyObjects').append('<tr><td>' + values.ID + 
                  '</td><td>' + values.Name + '</td><td>' + 
                  values.Value + '</td></tr>');
            });
        }
    }
    error: function () {
    }
});
```

If you want to replace all existing data into new ones, add `empty()` method before creating rows from response:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "MyAdmin.aspx/GetObject",
    data: JSON.stringify({ 'Value': Value }),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        $('#gvMyObjects').empty(); // remove all rows

        // append new header and rows
        if (data.d.length > 0) {
            $('#gvMyObjects').append('<tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Value</th></tr>');

            $.each(data, function (i, values) {
                // build table data
                $('#gvMyObjects').append('<tr><td>' + values.ID + 
                  '</td><td>' + values.Name + '</td><td>' + 
                  values.Value + '</td></tr>');
            });
        }
    }
    error: function () {
    }
});
```

If the grid selector doesn't work because the `GridView` has different client ID than server ID, use `$('#<%= gvMyObjects.ClientID %>')` or set `ClientIDMode="Static"`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer !